# PostgreSQL select statement to return rows after where condition

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, window-functions, self-join

I am working on a query to return the next 7 days worth of data every time an event happens indicated by "where event = 1". The goal is to then group all the data by the user id and perform aggregate functions on this data after the event happens - the event is encoded as binary [0, 1].

So far, I have been attempting to use nested select statements to structure the data how I would like to have it, but using the window functions is starting to restrict me. I am now thinking a self join could be more appropriate but need help in constructing such a query.

The query currently first creates daily aggregate values grouped by user and date (3rd level nested select). Then, the 2nd level sums the data "value_x" to obtain an aggregate value grouped by the user. Then, the 1st level nested select statement uses the lead function to grab the next rows value over and partitioned by each user which acts as selecting the next day's value when event = 1. Lastly, the select statement uses an aggregate function to calculate the average "sum_next_day_value_after_event" grouped by user and where event = 1. Put together, where event = 1, the query returns the avg(value_x) of the next row's total value_x.

However, this doesn't follow my time rule; "where event = 1", return the next 7 days worth of data after the event happens. If there is not 7 days worth of data, then return whatever data is <= 7 days. Yes, I currently only have one lead with the offset as 1, but you could just put 6 more of these functions to grab the next 6 rows. But, the lead function currently just grabs the next row without regard to date. So theoretically, the next row's "value_x" could actually be 15 days from where "event = 1". Also, as can be seen below in the data table, a user may have more than one row per day.

Here is the following query I have so far:

```
select 
    f.user_id
    avg(f.sum_next_day_value_after_event) as sum_next_day_values
from (
    select
        bld.user_id,
        lead(bld.value_x, 1) over(partition by bld.user_id order by bld.daily) as sum_next_day_value_after_event
    from (
        select 
            l.user_id, 
            l.daily, 
            sum(l.value_x) as sum_daily_value_x
        from (
            select
                user_id, value_x, date_part('day', day_ts) as daily
            from table_1
            group by date_part('day', day_ts), user_id, value_x) l
        group by l.user_id, l.day_ts
        order by l.user_id) bld) f
group by f.user_id
```

Below is a snippet of the data from table_1:

| user_id | day_ts | value_x | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 4/2/21 07:37 | 25 | 0 |
| 50 | 4/2/21 07:42 | 45 | 0 |
| 50 | 4/2/21 09:14 | 67 | 1 |
| 50 | 4/5/21 10:09 | 8 | 0 |
| 50 | 4/5/21 10:24 | 75 | 0 |
| 50 | 4/8/21 11:08 | 34 | 0 |
| 50 | 4/15/21 13:09 | 32 | 1 |
| 50 | 4/16/21 14:23 | 12 | 0 |
| 50 | 4/29/21 14:34 | 90 | 0 |
| 55 | 4/4/21 15:31 | 12 | 0 |
| 55 | 4/5/21 15:23 | 34 | 0 |
| 55 | 4/17/21 18:58 | 32 | 1 |
| 55 | 4/17/21 19:00 | 66 | 1 |
| 55 | 4/18/21 19:57 | 54 | 0 |
| 55 | 4/23/21 20:02 | 34 | 0 |
| 55 | 4/29/21 20:39 | 57 | 0 |
| 55 | 4/30/21 21:46 | 43 | 0 |

Technical details:

PostgreSQL, supported by EDB, version = 14.1

pgAdmin4, version 5.7

Thanks for the help!

Comment: An order by without top/limit in a subquery has no effect. Tables have no row order, result sets do. PS [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"The query currently first creates daily aggregate values"*

I don't see any aggregate function in your first query, so that the `GROUP BY` clause is useless.

```
select
    user_id, value_x, date_part('day', day_ts) as daily
from table_1
group by date_part('day', day_ts), user_id, value_x
```

could be simplified as

```
select
    user_id, value_x, date_part('day', day_ts) as daily
from table_1
```

which in turn provides no real added value, so this first query could be removed and the second query would become :

```
select user_id
     , date_part('day', day_ts) as daily
     , sum(value_x) as sum_daily_value_x
 from table_1
group by user_id, date_part('day', day_ts)
```

The `order by user_id` clause can also be removed at this step.

Now if you want to calculate the average value of the *sum_daily_value_x* in the period of 7 days after the event (I'm referring to the `avg()` function in your top query), you can use `avg()` as a window function that you can restrict to the period of 7 days after the event :

```
select f.user_id
     , avg(f.sum_daily_value_x) over (order by f.daily range between current row and '7 days' following) as sum_next_day_values
  from (
        select user_id
             , date_part('day', day_ts) as daily
             , sum(value_x) as sum_daily_value_x
          from table_1
         group by user_id, date_part('day', day_ts)
       ) AS f
 group by f.user_id
```

The `partition by f.user_id` clause in the window function is useless because the rows have already been grouped by *f.user_id* before the window function is applied.

You can replace the `avg()` window function by any other one, for instance `sum()` which could better fit with the alias *sum_next_day_values*

Comment: I appreciate the comments and addition of the `range between. . .following`. This part helped solve the problem. @Edouard H.